# How to add a logo to navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Hello all I'm trying to add a logo to my navigation bar using HTML and CSS I have managed to get an image loaded  on to my nav bar but it is way to big as seen in the picture. [image]

```
    <div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
            <img src="images/test.png">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How to</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to let it do it automatically but ill try that

Comment: you could try something like `<img src="images/test.png" height="20" width="20">`..

Comment: Thank you didn't think of that i will give it a go

Comment: @Lal that would perfectly conserve bandwidth. not!

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are several options.
First is to resize your image with any of editors like Photoshop and others.
Second is to set your image width and height via css:

```
.pull-left img {
    display: block;
    width: 30px; /* here put your width */
    height: 30px; /* here put your height */
}
```

But if your logo image not going to scale to it's initial size according to your design and media queries, you should take the first approach. It will reduce file size as well.

Comment: Thank you I used this method instead of changing the size of the image in an editor thanks!

Comment: This solution is kinda ... not good ... as not taking the fundamental resource of bandwidth into account...

Comment: I'm new to this and I thought this was a good method but if it is better to just change the size via editor Ill do that haha